# Como executar programas escritos em Python no windows ocultando feedback do terminal

Tags: python-2.7, flask, qtwebkit, webkit

Estou com a seguinte situação:
Tenho um programa escrito em python que trabalha com Gtk + webkit + flask.
Para executar tal programa devo entrar do CMD e digitar "python arquivo.py" e ele starta minha aplicação GUI normalmente. 
Onde conforme a utilização algumas mensagens de debug são empresas no terminal CMD.

Minha pergunta é a seguinte:

> Como iniciar minha aplicação python e "ocultar possíveis retorno de
>   erro no CMD"?

Algo como rodar o terminal em segundo plano.

Answer (score 7):

O Python no Windows tem dois executáveis. O `python.exe` e o `pythonw.exe`. A diferença entre eles é que o `pythonw.exe` não abre uma janela de terminal.

Se for para executar o programa clicando nele, dá para fazer com o `Abrir com` ou renomeando o arquivo para `.pyw`.

Pelo `cmd`, use `pythonw arquivo.py`.

Answer (score 0):

Já tentou renomear seu arquivo `.py` para `.pyw`? Isso faz com que o programa rode em background sem retorno do terminal.

Answer (score -1):

Não é preciso renomear o arquivo.
Informe o caminho do arquivo, escreva: `python` e o nome do arquivo e clique <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

```
$ C:\Users\wagne\OneDrive\Documentos\Python> python .\aula001.py
Olá mundo!
```

Comment: Mas precisa fazer isso a partir do terminal, obtendo, desta forma, o retorno com as mensagens, que é exatamente o que não é desejado pela pergunta. Poderia explicar melhor como sua resposta resolve o problema descrito?